# Can an ASP.NET TreeView expand upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview, orgchart

Can an ASP.NET TreeView, when you click the + sign be made to expand upwards instead of downwards?  So that "Children" nodes appear above their "Parents."

Essentially I want to logically be taking what would normally be a singular leaf node, making it the root of my tree, and making what is logically it's Parent into a Child Node on my Tree, but have that Child Node still display above the Parent when the Parent gets expanded.

Think a company OrgChart, but starting with the employee (leaf node) and going up.

I can't seem to find anything specifying direction on MSDN.  I would like to avoid having to re-write how the Javascript of the TreeView works, but would be open to it if no other way is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that with the `TreeView` component.
Attempting to do that would involve inheriting from the TreeView and writing your custom `Render` function.

There is a simpler approach to it though. You could write out all your data to a json object, and use one of the numerous javascript data visualization libraries to present it.

I really like the [javascript InfoVis toolkit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/). You can make very detailed graphs using it.